# How to use Response class with parameters created on other routes on Flask?

Tags: python, csv, variables, flask, return

I'm trying to export a Dataframe into CSV. For that I have a function called `create_simulation()` that gives me a new simulation and I call it on my my index route `@app.route("/")` so I can show the simulation into a Dataframe and its CSV.

There is also the route that was suposed to provide a download file of the generated simulation (`@app.route('/download')`). But the only way I can retrieve a download file is using `create_simulation` again on this route, which gives me a file with different values than the ones ploted on my index.

How can I use the variables created on `@app.route("/")` to provide a downloadable file with the same results as displayed on index `@app.route('/download')`?

views.py:

```
from flask import render_template, send_file, send_from_directory, safe_join, abort, make_response, Response
from flask import send_file
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random
import seaborn as sns
import sys

@app.route("/jinja")
def jinja():

    my_name = "Testes"

    return render_template("/public/jinja.html", my_name=my_name)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("/public/about.html")

#defining parameters
bast_param = [0,5] #ba prefix for below average student
avst_param = [5,7] #av prefix for average student
aast_param = [7,10] #aa prefix for above average student

min_bast = bast_param[0]
max_bast = bast_param[1]
min_avst = avst_param[0]
max_avst = avst_param[1]
min_aast = aast_param[0]
max_aast = aast_param[1]


#RELEVANT FOR STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION
@app.route("/")
def index():
    simulation = create_simulation()
    return render_template('/public/index.html',table=simulation.to_html(),download_csv=simulation.to_csv(index=True, sep=";"))


#RELEVANT FOR STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    # stream the response as the data is generated
    simulation = create_simulation()
    response = Response(
        simulation.to_csv(),
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=grades_simulation.csv"})
    # add a filename

    return response


@app.route("/parameters")
def parameters():

    return render_template('/public/parameters.html', min_bast=min_bast, max_bast=max_bast, min_avst=min_avst,max_avst=max_avst, min_aast=min_aast, max_aast=max_aast)



#RELEVANT FOR STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION
def create_simulation():

    #students quantities per parameter
    bast_qtd = 5
    avst_qtd = 3
    aast_qtd = 8
    st_total = bast_qtd + avst_qtd + aast_qtd

    #Defining Subjects
    subjects = ["Disciplina 1", "Disciplina 2", "Disciplina 3", "Disciplina 4", "Disciplina 5"]

    students = []

    #counter for students ids creation
    i = 0

    #counters and variable for grades creation
    a = 0
    b = 0
    newgradeline = []

    grade = []

    #creating students and grades
    while(i < st_total):
        newstudent = random.randint(100000,199999)
        #excluding duplicates
        if newstudent not in students:
            students.append(newstudent)
            i = i+1


    # In[3]:


    #below averagge students
    while (a < bast_qtd):
        b = 0
        newgradeline = []
        grade.append(newgradeline)
        while (b<len(subjects)):
            gen_grade = round(random.uniform(bast_param[0],bast_param[1]),2)
            newgradeline.append(gen_grade)
            b = b+1
        a = a +1
    a = 0

    #average students
    while (a < avst_qtd):
        b = 0
        newgradeline = []
        grade.append(newgradeline)
        while (b<len(subjects)):
            gen_grade = round(random.uniform(avst_param[0],avst_param[1]),2)
            newgradeline.append(gen_grade)
            b = b+1
        a = a +1
    a = 0

    #above average students
    while (a < aast_qtd):
        b = 0
        newgradeline = []
        grade.append(newgradeline)
        while (b<len(subjects)):
            gen_grade = round(random.uniform(aast_param[0],aast_param[1]),2)
            newgradeline.append(gen_grade)
            b = b+1
        a = a +1


    # In[4]:
    #generating table
    simulation = pd.DataFrame (grade,index=students, columns=subjects)
    return simulation
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "/public/templates/public_template.html" %}

{% block  title %}Simulador{% endblock%}

{% block main %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </br>
        <h1>Simulador</h1>
      <hr/>
        {{table| safe}}
        <br />
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/" role="button">New simulation</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/parameters" role="button">Edit Parameters</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
      </br>
      <hr/>
        <h1>CSV File</h1>
        {{download_csv | safe}}
      </br></br>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/download" role="button">Download CSV</a>
        <hr/>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have 3 options:

1) Store the result in a database and provide some kind of unique id to the index view page so that when you click the download button it looks up the relevant data and builds the CSV files. This is a good solution but requires a database backend which might be complicated to set up if you have never before.

2) Pass the data back and forth. You could use `df.to_json()` to pass JSON data which is stored in the view and when the button is clicked it submits a POST request with the necessary JSON data from which you can reconstruct the DataFrame. You might be able to use a hidden form field to store the data.
E.g.

```
<form action="/download" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="df" name="df" value="{{ df_json }}">
    <submit>Download</submit>
</form>

@route('/download', methods=["POST"])
def download():
    data = request.form['df']
    df = pd.from_json(data)
```

3) Store the result in `session`. Doing this allows data to be passed from one view to another, but it is more difficult to control and requires error trapping for when the views are not performed syncronously. In this case it would probably work but I would not recommend it as a production solution.